# ASP.NET MVC3 Editor Templates for interface or inherited classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvc-editor-templates

Need to use a "EditorTemplate" employing an interface, in the same manner that would use a class.

I have two problems:

1. I only recognize the "EditorTemplate" if I include the "DataAnnotation" "DataType" with the name of "EditorTemplate". This does not bother me much, but it would be nice to be able to recognize it by type, as it did if it had a "EditorTemplate" with the name of my type (class). `[DataType ("ICanBeListed")]`
2. My interface uses generics to define the list and return type of property. For this reason I do not know how to do the template.

I know there are two queries but do the same problem.

Archives:

Desirable view model:

```
[DisplayName("Field one")]
public FieldOne MyFieldOne { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Field two")]
public FieldTwo MyFieldTwo { get; set; }
```

Solution for point 1:

```
[DisplayName("Field one")]
[DataType("ICanBeListed")]
public FieldOne MyFieldOne { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Field two")]
[DataType("ICanBeListed")]
public FieldTwo MyFieldTwo { get; set; }
```

Interface:

```
public interface ICanBeListed<T, U>
{
    U Id { get; set; }

    string Description { get; set; }

    IList<T> ToList();
}
```

Classes:

```
public class FieldOne : ICanBeListed<FieldOne, string>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public IList<FieldOne> List()
    {
        return new List<FieldOne>
        {
            new FieldOne{Id = "1", Descripcion = "Description 1"},
            new FieldOne{Id = "2", Descripcion = "Description 2"}
        };
    }
}


public class FieldTwo : ICanBeListed<FieldTwo, int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public IList<FieldTwo> List()
    {
        return new List<FieldTwo>
        {
            new FieldTwo{Id = 1, Descripcion = "Descripcion 1"},
            new FieldTwo{Id = 2, Descripcion = "Descripcion 2"}
        };
    }
}
```

Template editor:

```
@model Mvc3ConditionalValidation.Models.ICanBeListed<object, object>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.ToList(), "Id", "Description"))
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyFieldOne)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyFieldOne)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyFieldTwo)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyFieldTwo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyFieldTwo)
</div>
```

I try to change the interface for a class:

View model:

```
public class FieldTwo : CanBeListed<FieldTwo, int>
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public override string Description { get; set; }

    public override IList<FieldTwo> ForList()
    {
        return new List<FieldTwo>
        {
            new FieldTwo{Id = 1, Description = "Descripcion 1"},
            new FieldTwo{Id = 2, Description = "Descripcion 2"}
        };
    }
}
```

Class (before interface):

```
public abstract class CanBeListed<T, U>
{
    public virtual U Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public abstract IList<T> ForList();
}
```

But the problem is the same:

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Mvc3ConditionalValidation.Models.FieldOne', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Mvc3ConditionalValidation.Models.CanBeListed`2[System.Object,System.Object]'.**

Thanks

Comment: Any solutions or workarounds to this?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring that the EditorTemplate can only take a `ICanBeListed<object, object>`. Basically, you're declaring that you want to use the same `ICanBeListed<,>` template for two different types, which is not what you want to be doing. You need to create an EditorTemplate for `FieldOne` and `FieldTwo` which are distinct, so that you can correctly make the model type match.

Comment: ok, but this is exactly what I want to avoid doing, I'm looking to resolve this as it is to "FF" and I have many ViewModel's. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that this line of code is invalid: `ICanBeListed<object, object> example = new FieldTwo()` - And no combination of `ICanBeListed<in T, in U>` for example makes it valid.

Comment: +1, @Tejs ok, I know it is wrong, but I wanted to know if there was any solution to this probema.